# Значок "+" в положительных значениях

Tags: c++, математика

Как поставить знак "+" в положительных значениях в C++? Есть код, который должен вычислять квадратный корень и выводить переменные после каждого ввода. То есть не 2x^2 3x 4, а 2x^2 + 3x + 4

P.S Код не закончен

---

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <cmath>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); // Локаль консоли
    int a, b, c;
    cout << "Введите a, b, c: (Без x): " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << a << "x ^ 2 ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << a << "x ^ 2 " << b <<  " x ";
    cin >> c ;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cin >> b;
cout << a << "x ^ 2 " << ((b < 0)?"- ":"+ ")  << abs(b) <<  " x ";
```

Comment: На знаке + ошибка. Выражение должно относится к целочисленномк типу данных или типу пересечения без области видимости

Comment: @Егор Смирнов Выражение c условием возьмите в скобки ***cout << a << "x ^ 2 " << ( (b < 0)?"- ":"+ " ) << abs(b) <<  " x ";*** и будет vote :)

Answer (score 9):

Как альтернатива, можете воспользоваться манипулятором форматирования `std::showpos`, который как раз и предназначен для того, чтобы выводить знак плюс для положительных чисел:

```
int negativeNumber = -1;
int positiveNumber = 1;
std::cout << std::showpos << negativeNumber << positiveNumber; // -1+1
```

---

Во избежание лишнего знака `+` в случае, если в начале выражения стоит положительное число, следует данный манипулятор применить чуть позднее:

```
int positiveNumber = 1;
int positiveNumber2 = 2;
std::cout << std::showpos << positiveNumber << positiveNumber2;                   // +1+2
std::cout << std::noshowpos << positiveNumber << std::showpos << positiveNumber2; // 1+2
```